# How to prevent IE dialog box "Always Ask Before Opening This Type of Address" from opening?

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I am canceling the checkbox when the website try to open an app from URL procotol.
so how can I fix this?
let IE show me this alert "always ask before opening this type of address" again.
I remember modify the windows registry can fix this, but I forget how.


this is my computer info:

```
windows10 x64 and browser:IE 11
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @libertyernie yes,just like this [img](https://upload.cc/i/CNb2G0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [Microsoft Answers post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/always-ask-before-opening-this-type-of-file/15c2c023-80ff-467d-8f1f-b91305293bad):

> The user may control whether this prompt appears by unticking the **Always ask before opening this type of address** box; the decision is stored inside a REG_DWORD named **WarnOnOpen** inside **HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute**; the default value is **0x1**, which enables the warning, and the value **0x0** disables the warning. The HKLM version of this key is also respected in the event that the administrator or application developer has set the policy on the user’s behalf, but for security reasons suppressing this prompt is generally discouraged.

Comment: thank you so much!! I finally find the "WarnOnOpen" option by my customer protocol

Comment: You can also put it in `HKLM` if you want it to apply to all users